# IllegalArgumentException the bind value index 1 is null with SQLite database in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to display average of all the column from SQLite database in listview . I'm using average function and group by clause in the query but when i run the app my app is crashing and getting **IllegalArgumentException** and the bind value index 1 is null.

I don't know where is my mistake and even i'm not inserted any null value in SQLite db.SO can help me some one. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
private void showPerformanceDetails()
    {
        ArrayList<Performance_Pojo> Performance_PojoList = new ArrayList<Performance_Pojo>();  
        Performance_PojoList.clear();   

        SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = sqlDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT performance_month, AVG(performance_rate_one),  AVG(performance_rate_two),  AVG(performance_rate_three),  AVG(performance_rate_four),  AVG(performance_rate_five)  FROM performance where "+ "Emp_id" + " = ? " 
                +" GROUP BY performance_month",new String[]{strSeparated_Id});


        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) 
        { 
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    Performance_Pojo Performance_PojoListItems = new Performance_Pojo();  

                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformanceMonth(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_month")));
                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_one(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_one")));
                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_two(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_two")));
                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_three(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_three")));
                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_four(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_four")));
                    Performance_PojoListItems.set_strPerformance_rate_five(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_five")));

                    Performance_PojoList.add(Performance_PojoListItems);     

                }while (cursor.moveToNext());   
            }

            db.close();
            cursor.close();

        }


        PerformanceList_Adapter performanceList_Adapter = new PerformanceList_Adapter(Performance_Details.this, Performance_PojoList); 
        list_PerformanceDetails.setAdapter(performanceList_Adapter);  

    }
```

Here is my Log cat error:

```
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sqlitedemo/com.sqlitedemo.Performance_Details}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:237)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.bindString(SQLiteQuery.java:185)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:48)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at com.sqlitedemo.Performance_Details.showPerformanceDetails(Performance_Details.java:79)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at com.sqlitedemo.Performance_Details.onCreate(Performance_Details.java:63)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-01 12:15:15.366: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: it seems `strSeparated_Id` is coming as null. print the value in log and check

Comment: @Sanjeev : I have to check my log and I'm getting value in strSeparated_Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The bind value" apparently refers to the selectionArgs for the selection, that you select into rawQuery(). If such a selArgs value is null, you get this.

Edit:

```
    Cursor cursor = sqlDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT performance_month, AVG(performance_rate_one),  AVG(performance_rate_two),  AVG(performance_rate_three),  AVG(performance_rate_four),  AVG(performance_rate_five)  FROM performance where "+ "Emp_id" + " = ? " 
            +" GROUP BY performance_month",new String[]{strSeparated_Id});
```

All parameter places should be designated with ?. The parameters to the query are always string nontheless, so nothing special about the integers. This should work for you:

Change:

```
new String[]{strSeparated_Id}
```

to

```
new String[]{String.valueOf(strSeparated_Id)}
```

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get you.

Comment: @ TeRRo : But i'm getting value strSeparated_Id = 1 so how will null ?

Comment: @ TeRRo:I have done all steps what you have said but query showing no records.

Comment: @Robotics But you do not get errors? Are you sure you have inserted data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56579/discussion-between-robotics-and-terro).